# How to record audio within a application on a mobile device, by not using the built in microphone

Tags: javascript, cordova, audio-recording

Im developing an application (with phonegap) where I want the user to be able to record his/her voice, when pushing/holding a button. So far, I have only figured out one way to do this, by using phongap's capture audio method. When I click on the button, the device's audio recording application is launched.

So my question, is it possible to record an audio within the application by simply holding down a button, without launching the device's recording application?

```
<button id="record" d  class="btn btn-xlarge"> Record </button> 
 $("#record").mousedown(function(){
        // Start the recording, maximum 10 seconds save the audio file 
 });
 $("#record").mouseup(function(){
        // stop the recording and save the audio file 
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the Catpure object, you may use the Media object:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media

This object makes it possible to interface the mic directly, without launching the device's audio recording application.

Some examples are found here:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.startRecord_quick_example

Comment: Im trying to create a new media with phonegap. It works on android but not iphone, Im using phonegap 3.3. I have tried everything but cant find the error. 

              my_media = null;
              src = "rec.mp3";
              alert("before mediaRec");
              mediaRec = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
              alert("after rec");

Only the first alert pop up :(

Comment: What does onSuccess and onError look like? Are they at all defined? You know they are function callbacks you need to implement?